# Getting &error Without Error

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nserror

For some reason I am getting an error when no error exists when I do a `NSURLConnection`.

```
NSLog(@"Sending string to server. ID:11118");
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Response from server received. ID:11119");
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if (&error)
    {
        //Handle Error
        NSLog(@"Error getting a server response! (scm) Error %i: %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
        UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error getting a server response!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error %i: %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [theAlert show];
    }
```

It is showing the alert with `[error code]` showing `0` and the `[error localizedDescription]` showing `Null`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't check `NSError` objects to determine if an error has occurred. By convention, you should be checking the return value of the method that generated the error. If the result is `nil` or `NO`, only then should you proceed with checking the error. Additionally, you're not checking the error object, you're checking for the validity of an address in memory of the error object.

In your case, only proceed with inspecting the error if `urlData` is `nil`.

Comment: Wouldn't he look for `urlData` to be `nil`, not `responseString`?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're checking the address of the error object.  You need to check the object itself.

```
if (error != nil)
```

instead of

```
if (&error)
```

The latter form evaluates the address of the error object, which will be nonzero, so your error condition will always run.

(And don't forget to set the error value to nil beforehand).

Comment: Also, you should *never* examine an error returned through an out parameter *unless* the normal result is `nil`/`NO`/etc. Its value is considered undefined in Cocoa except in that case.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Whoops! Thank you. (waiting until the time passes to accept)

Comment: Can't believe this is the highest voted answer. Where's @bbum when you need him...

Comment: @bbum is probably doing work, like all of us should be doing ;)  And while stevex's is the first correct answer, your additional answer has useful detail, so another +1 to you.

Answer (score -1):

initialize error to nil first:

```
NSError * error = nil;
```

and when you want to look at the error, do:

```
if(error)
{
    //Handle Error
```

Comment: This is not correct. Cocoa does not guarantee that `error` will be `nil` if the call succeeds; you _must_ check the direct return value to determine if there was an error.